# data from excel read and Remove blank row and fetch data from row add to list from Array List

Tags: java, arrays, apache-poi

How can I remove blank Row and Cell from Array list.
I have used myList.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null)); 
This line does help me to remove blank cell. but it still add blank row to the list.
Also can I add read all data as per row and add list as row.

Except Output as list row.

```
    [DataGrouping RWAExposureType AA RWA ex 1.06x AA RWA SA RWA, Credit Available For Sale $ 449,454 $ 476,421 $ 264,503,Contingent $ 113,262 $ 120,057 $ 258,508,Total $ 562,715 $ 596,478 $ 523,011, Total $ 562,715 $ 596,478 $ 523,011]
```

Code for read Excel

```
      ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\resources\\excelfiles\\Mode Report.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    CreationHelper creationHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    // Read sheet inside the workbook by its name
    XSSFSheet sh1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    // Data formatter
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = creationHelper.createFormulaEvaluator();

     for (Row row : sh1) {
         if (row == null) {

         }
    for (Cell cell : row) {

        CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
        String dataFormatString = cellStyle.getDataFormatString();

        if (dataFormatString != null && dataFormatString.contains(";"))
            cellStyle.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat(dataFormatString + ";"));


        String cellContent = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);

        myList.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
        myList.add(cellContent);

    }
     }
        System.out.println(myList + "lisi");
```

OUTput with removeAll Still fetch blank row from the excel

```
        [


        , Data Grouping, RWA Exposure Type, ( $ M ) AA RWA ex 1.06x, ( $ M ) AA RWA, ( $ M ) SA RWA, Credit, $ 562,715, $ 596,478, $ 523,011, Available For Sale, $ 449,454, $ 476,421, $ 264,503, Contingent, $ 113,262, $ 120,057, $ 258,508, Total, $ 562,715, $ 596,478, $ 523,011, 5/6/2019 2:23:35 PM
        , ]lisi
```

Output without removeAll.
            [

```
        , , , , , Data Grouping, RWA Exposure Type, ( $ M ) AA RWA ex 1.06x, ( $ M ) AA RWA, ( $ M ) SA RWA, Credit, , $ 562,715, $ 596,478, $ 523,011, , Available For Sale, $ 449,454, $ 476,421, $ 264,503, , Contingent, $ 113,262, $ 120,057, $ 258,508, Total, , $ 562,715, $ 596,478, $ 523,011, 5/6/2019 2:23:35 PM
        , , , , ]lisi
```

Expect OUTPUT Should be

```
        [Data Grouping, RWA Exposure Type, ( $ M ) AA RWA ex 1.06x, ( $ M ) AA RWA, ( $ M ) SA RWA, Credit, $ 562,715, $ 596,478, $ 523,011, Available For Sale, $ 449,454, $ 476,421, $ 264,503, Contingent, $ 113,262, $ 120,057, $ 258,508, Total, $ 562,715, $ 596,478, $ 523,011, 5/6/2019 2:23:35 PM]lisi
```

Comment: Looks like neither `null` nor `""` which only leaves actual spaces or tabs. Your best bet is to check before adding. `if(cellContent != null && !cellContent.trim().isEmpty()) myList.add(cellContent);`

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Then you are going to need a `List<List<String>>` to make this effectively. Also you still need to loop over all cells in each row (you probably want to add empty cells then as well)

Answer (score 0):

As per comment from XtremeBaumer

```
if(cellContent != null && !cellContent.trim().isEmpty())
myList.add(cellContent);
```